# In SQLite, showing missmatch even number of '?' s in statement string is equal to the number of argument count

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

While trying to insert the multiple records in SQLite, even passing same number of argument as ? in INSERT statement, but its giving error with the message of mismatch of number of argument and '?'s in INSERT statement.

### Code for Multiple insertion in SQLite

```
                    var query01 = "INSERT INTO TBL_JCI_CONTENT (slug, title, content) VALUES ";      

                    var insertdata = [];
                    var rowArgs = [];
                    home_content.forEach(function (category) {
                          rowArgs.push('( ?, ?, ? )');
                          insertdata.push(category.slug);
                          insertdata.push(category.title);
                          insertdata.push(category.content);
                    });

                    query01 += rowArgs.join(', ');
                    console.log(query01);
                    console.log(insertdata);

                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query01, [insertdata]).then(function(res) {
                      console.log('Successfully Inserted Home Content');
                }, function (err) {
                      console.error(err);  
                });
```

### While running this code I am getting following error:

```
Object {home_page: Array[6]}
controllers.js:83 INSERT INTO TBL_JCI_CONTENT (slug, title, content) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ), ( ?, ?, ? )
Array[6]
0: “home”
1: “Home”
2: “HMI is a nonprofit “
3: "mission"
4: "Mission"
5: "We develop the skills
length: 6__proto__: Array[0]
controllers.js:89 SQLError {code: 5, message: "number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count"}
```

[image]

Refer many stackflow answers but couldn't get the solution way around.

Comment: Does inserting multiple rows at once work without parameters? Does inserting with parameters work with a single row?

Comment: It works when I insert it one by one in a forEach loop.

Comment: Does inserting multiple rows at once work without parameters?